# spring data jpa and commons compatibility

Tags: spring, jpa, version-control, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-commons

I meet an exception running a project using spring data jpa

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 18 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 51; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:repositories' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

I read through many docs and blogs and I think this is possibly caused by incompatibility of spring data jpa and spring data commons package versions.

Now I'm using

- spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.Release
- spring-data-commons-1.10.0.release
- spring-data-jpa-1.8.0.

Any suggestion on the version control to get rid of such error?

Also I would like to ask for suggestions how to make such version control easier(any website, docs or tools). Thanks for advice in advance.

Below is the namespace I use

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">
```

The `repository:repository` is not from my `applicationContext.xml`. I did use `jpa:repository` as

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.canreef.calendar"/>
```

Comment: `repository:repositories` should be `jpa:repositories`... For managing your dependencies use something like maven or gradle don't go searching for yourself.

Comment: I did use the jpa:repository

Comment: @Deinum I did use jpa:repository, that repository:repository must come from an xml. I've added to the post, pls check.

Comment: As mentioned don't search for dependencies yourself, use maven to do that for you... Saves you a lot of headaches. Remove the `spring-data-commons-core` jar as that is old, really old... Also why do you need that `spring-repository.xsd` in your declaration? If you aren't using it just remove  it.

Comment: @Deinum Thanks for your suggestion but removing the repository.xsd dependency unfortunately didn't help. I removed the entries related to repository in namespace, but the exception is the same.

Comment: As stated remove the old dependency as that is from 2013 and not relevant anymore. I also suggested that you should use something like maven to manage your dependencies instead of trying to find workable combinations yourself.

Comment: Yes I am using maven to manage the dependency and now I'm pretty sure there is no trouble with the dependencies. I just found this problem roots in the spring-repository.xsd

Comment: No it isn't... You have an old dependency... Which you shouldn't use remove that dependency... You should only have spring-data-jpa and spring-data-commons nothing more for spring-data.

Answer (score 0):

I found this roots in spring-repository.xsd
In spring-jpa.xsd there is a line with ref to repository:auditing-attributes:

```
<xsd:element name="auditing">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation>
                    <tool:exports type="org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener" />
                    <tool:exports type="org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler" />
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="repository:auditing-attributes" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

While in spring-repository.xsd there is the bean:

```
-<xsd:attributeGroup name="auditing-attributes">


-<xsd:attribute name="auditor-aware-ref">


-<xsd:annotation>


-<xsd:documentation>

<![CDATA[ References a bean of type AuditorAware to represent the current principal. ]]>

</xsd:documentation>


-<xsd:appinfo>


-<tool:annotation kind="ref">

<tool:assignable-to type="org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware"/>

</tool:annotation>

</xsd:appinfo>

</xsd:annotation>

</xsd:attribute>


...omitted...

</xsd:attributeGroup>
```

Therefore this should be caused by not able to fetch the repository.xsd.

Comment: Does any have any ideas where this spring-repository.xsd resides? I can't find it in any jar.

Comment: Since this seems to be another problem I simply started another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542876/cannot-resolve-the-name-repositoryrepositories-to-an-type-definition-comp